# Find connections between values of one column in R and build network grapgh

Tags: r, networking, filter, ggraph

I want to count how many common values do rows of a column have with each other.

This is what my dataframe looks like:

| Location | Manager |
| --- | --- |
| L1 | M45 |
| L2 | M45 |
| L34 | M12 |
| L5 | M45 |
| L23 | M12 |
| L4 | M3 |
| L11 | M45 |

I want to create a new dataframe with two columns: Location and Links. The new Links column should  contain all the locations over the common manager. So, since L1, L2 and L5 have a common manager they should be linked together and so on.

| Location | Manager |
| --- | --- |
| L1 | L2,L5 |
| L2 | L1,L5 |
| L5 | L23 |
| L5 | L1,L2 |
| L23 | L34 |
| L4 |  |
| L11 |  |

After this, can we create a network graph?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part (getting all locations covered by a manager in a single row) we can do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Manager) %>%
  summarize(Location = paste(Location, collapse = ", "))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Manager Location       
#>   <chr>   <chr>          
#> 1 M12     L34, L23       
#> 2 M3      L4             
#> 3 M45     L1, L2, L5, L11
```

Your original data frame is already in the correct format to make a graph:

```r
plot(tidygraph::as_tbl_graph(df))
```

[image]

If you want a prettier representation of the graph, you could use `ggraph`, for example:

```r
library(ggraph)

df[2:1] %>%
  rbind(data.frame(Manager = "Managers", Location = unique(df$Manager))) %>%
  tidygraph::as_tbl_graph() %>%
  ggraph(circular = TRUE) +
  geom_edge_bend() +
  geom_node_circle(aes(r = ifelse(name == "Managers", 0, 0.1),
                       fill = substr(name, 1, 1))) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = ifelse(name == "Managers", "", name))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("deepskyblue", "gold"),
                    labels = c("Managers", "Locations"),
                    name = NULL) +
  theme_void(base_size = 16) +
  coord_equal()
```

### [image]

**Question data in reproducible format**

```r
df <- data.frame(Location = c("L1", "L2", "L34", "L5", "L23", "L4", "L11"), 
                 Manager = c("M45", "M45", "M12", "M45", "M12", "M3", "M45"))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>